# In a research paper, is it acceptable to include expletives in the results of a text analysis?

Tags: writing

Currently, I am doing a research paper and as a result from my text analysis, I found a record which contains a (*UCK) word. Is it ethical if I submit it as it is to a conference? Hereby in the image (in the third record) 
[image]

Comment: What's the alternative - just omit it?  Surely that would be unethical data manipulation?

Comment: What does this possibly have to do with ethics?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is ethical.  When you play Scrabble with other enthusiasts, bad words are perfectly acceptable and no one bats an eyelash.